# How to out put a 2-D array, which is dynamically evaluated in a python code, come out as a table?

Tags: python, matrix, indentation

At the moment, I use the following code to output an array but it does not come out aligned very well for 2 digit numbers.

```
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        print '{:2}'.format(Matrix[i][j]),
    print
```

Output:

```
 0 M Y M I S S I S A H I P P I E I
I 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
M 1   .                          
I 2     .     .       .     .   .
S 3       . .   .                
S 4       . .   .                
M 5   .                          
I 6     .     .       .     .   .
S 7       . .   .                
S 8       . .   .                
I 9     .     .       .     .   .
S 10       . .   .                
S 11       . .   .                
I 12     .     .       .     .   .
P 13                     . .      
P 14                     . .      
I 15     .     .       .     .   .
```

Comment: The Best possible way would be to have it come in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
print '\n'.join(' '.join('%2s' % cell for cell in row) for row in matrix)
```